# Setting a parent is asking for a string?

Tags: lua, roblox

when I try to set the parent of a clone it asks for a string?

```
            local cloned = game.ReplicatedFirst.menu:Clone()
         -->cloned.Parent = game.Players[player].PlayerGui
            cloned["home screen"].Enabled = true
            print("wellcome "..player.Name)
```

and I don't know what to do?

Comment: how is it "asking for a string"? are you getting an error? if so what is that specific error

Answer (score -1):

You are likely getting a "String expected got Instance" error, and it is pointing at this : `game.Players[player]`

That is because you are trying to find a child of the Players service with the `player` variable. But that `player` variable is likely a Player instance, not a string. So, since the children of the Players service are indexed by string, and not by objects, it is throwing the error.

You could fix this by passing in the correct data type : `game.Players[player.Name]`, or you could use the player object you already have.

```
cloned.Parent = player.PlayerGui
```